# How to create a file using a variable as filename?

Tags: bash

I'm testing mobile Android devices and I would like to redirect the device log on a file whose name indicates both the date and time of my test, and the device model that is being tested.
For the first issue, I have already resolved with

```
now=$(date +"%b_%d_%Y_%k_%M");adb logcat -c;adb logcat|tee $now
```

So:

```
$ echo $now
Jan_03_2012_13_09
```

and the tee command creates a file with this filename.

As for the device model I have written two bash lines that obtain it from adb shell, namely

```
device=$(adb shell cat /system/build.prop | grep "^ro.product.device=")
deviceshortname=$(echo $device | sed 's/ro.product.device=//g')
```

(not optimal as I am not very good in bash programming... :) but I manage to get

```
$ echo $deviceshortname
LT15i
```

My problem is how to combine `$now` and `$deviceshortname` to obtain a filename such as:
`LT15i_Jan_03_2012_13_19`

I tried to set another variable:

```
filename=($(echo $deviceshortname"_"$now))
```

and got:

```
$ echo $filename
LT15i_Jan_03_2012_13_19
```

but if I try redirecting the log:
    $ adb logcat | tee $filename

I obtain such file:

```
-rw-r--r--+ 1 ele None     293 Jan  3 13:21 ?[01;31m?[K?[m?[KLT15i_Jan_03_2012_13_19
```

I don't know why these strange characters and what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I'm curious what `echo $deviceshortname | xxd` output gives you.

Comment: @sarnold:  $ echo $deviceshortname | xxd
0000000: 1b5b 3031 3b33 316d 1b5b 4b1b 5b6d 1b5b  .[01;31m.[K.[m.[
0000010: 4b4c 5431 3569 0a                        KLT15i.

Comment: You're working too hard to set the `filename` variable: `filename="${deviceshortname}_$now"`. If you have awk, you can simplify setting `deviceshortname`: `deviceshortname=$(adb shell cat /system/build.prop | awk -F= '$1=="ro.product.device" {print $2}')`

Comment: @glennjackman: yes, i have awk, I'm just not familiar with it (nor with sed ;-) ) Thanks, I will try to apply your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something is adding color to your output. It might be `grep(1)`, it might `adb`, it might be baked into the `/system/build.prop` resource that you're reading.

If you're lucky, it is being added by `grep(1)` -- because that is supremely easy to disable with `--color=no`:

```
device=$(adb shell cat /system/build.prop | grep --color=no "^ro.product.device=")
deviceshortname=$(echo $device | sed 's/ro.product.device=//g')
```

If the colors are being added by `adb`, then perhaps it has a command line option that asks it to avoid colorizing the output.

If the colors are hard-coded into the `/sys/build.prop` resource in some way, then you'll need some little tool that filters out the color codes. I don't have one handy (and it's bedtime) but you can probably build one starting with `tr(1)` to delete `\033` ASCII `ESC` characters.

Comment: yes it was grep! I had added myself color to be facilitated in reading grep output...  Setting color=no solved my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like an ANSI sequence used by `adb` to color the output.

Comment: Maybe I'm starting to understand...  in the adb shell output, ro.product.device was red. The actual device name was not colored, but with my sed command, I just substituted the string, not the sequence that colored the output.  Makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm missing something, but this works for me

p1=foo
   p2=$(date +%d_%m_%Y)

cat sample_file.txt | tee $p1"_"$p2

Answer (score 0):

Just type: `echo ${deviceshortname}${now}` and it will do the trick.